# Creating dynamic 2D array c++

Tags: c++

From what I know, declaring a dynamic array is:

```
int *array = new int[x];
```

My question is, how can I declare a dynamic 2D array?

For example:

```
int *array = new int[constant][dynamic];
```

And from what I found out is the number of rows can't be dynamic.
Are there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy technique that I use in these kind of situations is that I create a struct for storing the 1D array, and create an array of those 1D arrays.

```cpp
struct BaseArray {
    BaseArray() = default;
    BaseArray(int count) : pArray(new int[count]) {}
    ~BaseArray() { delete[] pArray; }
    int* pArray = nullptr;
};


int main()
{
    BaseArray* pArray = new BaseArray[constant]{dynamic};
}
```

Now the other simple way is to use `std::vector`. It'll look something like this,

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(constant, std::vector<int>(dynamic));
```

I recommend using `std::vector` as its more feature complete and takes a lot of burden off of your shoulder.

Comment: How may I able to access the element inside the array if I decided to use `std::vector`. I had tried to do a `array.pushback()`, and of course it didn't work. And I was thinking of using `std::vector <int>::iterator`, but not sure on how to start. Thanks

Comment: @HuanShengTew As you can see, the first vector stores an array of `std::vector<int>`s. So when you do `array[index]`, you actually get access to `std::vector<int>`. Then you can push back or access elements.